# Time Capsule and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, time-capsule

I have recently reinstalled Windows 7 on my laptop. This was no problem and everything worked well. I have installed F-Secure anti-virus, also working well.

Then I installed Apple airport utility so I can reconnect to my time capsule and Airport Express with speakers. I can't find either one from my laptop with the Airport utility. I tried resetting the Airport Express, but that only led to more frustration because I can't even find it when I connect it with the Ethernet cable.

What am I doing wrong? What is blocking me from viewing the apple hardware?

Comment: Have you tried disabling F-Secure and/or Windows Firewall?  Is network discovery enabled in Windows 7?

Comment: oke, yeah i unstalled f-secure and it seemed to work, now to figure out why it blocks it and how to undo that

Answer (score 0):

Since you figured out it was F-Secure preventing the networking here's some info on allowing the Windows 7 HomeGroup networking through, which may be enough to ge tit working for you as you want it, or at least point you in the right direction on adding the allow rule.

From [F-Secure's KB](http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global/support/article/kba/15467/k/home/p/3):

> To set up the F-Secure firewall for your homegroup:
>
> 1. On the product main page, click Settings > Network connections > Firewall.
> 2. On the Rules tab, click Add. The Add New Rule dialog box opens.
> 3. In the Name field, type Homegroup.
> 4. Select Allow as the rule type and click Next.
> 5. To select the IP address range for this rule, select first the Custom option and then click Edit.
> 6. From the Type drop-down list, select MyNetwork , click Add to list and then OK.
> 7. Click Next.
> 8. Add the following services for the rule by selecting the corresponding check boxes and select the direction of the traffic - both inbound and outbound - by clicking the icon in the Direction column so that a double-headed arrow is visible:
>
>    - IGMP/Internet Group Management Protocol
>    - Windows file sharing and network printers
>    - Windows network browsing
>    - SMB over TCP/IP (TCP)
>    - SMB over TCP/IP (UDP)
> 9. Click Next.
> 10. If you want the alert to be logged or also shown as a pop-up, select either one of the options. In this case, we select the No alert option.
> 11. Click Next. The summary of the rule you are about to create is displayed.
> 12. Click Finish to create the rule.
> 13. On the Firewall page, click the Settings tab.
> 14. In the Select IPv6 traffic filtering options field, select Normal from the drop-down list. This will allow IPv6 traffic to be filtered.
> 15. Click OK.
>
> You are now ready to set up your Windows 7 HomeGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Time Capsule on Windows XP, 2000, Vista, Windows 7/8/8.1, and Windows 10

Ethernet Connection Setup & Internet Sharing with Time Capsule Drive.
*Time Capsule must be connected to your PC.*

1. Download and install AirPort Utility.
2. In AirPort Utility you will find your Time Capsule. Click on it and the click *Manual Setup*.
3. Go to *Disks* tab and check *File Sharing*. Some blogs will confuse you about Workgroup name. Just ignore or leave it blank.
4. In *AirPort* tab go to *Time Capsule*. Choose your Time Capsule drive name. Set up a password so your Time Capsule network drive will be protected.
5. Go to *Wireless*. Set up as you like. In my case I am sharing my Wi-Fi adapter Internet connection to Time Capsule and am using Time Capsule as a router with the option *Create a wireless network*.
6. Go to *Internet* tab -> *Internet Connection* -> Connect Using (Ethernet) -> Connection Sharing [Off (bridge mode)].
7. Go to TCP/IP.
8. IPV4 Using DHCP.
9. DNS Server must be 192.168.137.1
10. Domain Name: mshome.net

Windows Setup

1. Go to *Network and file sharing*.
2. Choose your Ethernet card.
3. Click *Properties*.
4. Double-click TCP/IPV4.
5. Use the following IP configuration:

   - *IP Address*: 192.168.137.1
   - *Subnet Mask*: 255.255.255.0
   - *Default Gateway*: leave blank
6. DNS you can leave empty, if not you can use Google DNS.

   - *Preferred DNS*: 8.8.8.8
   - *Alternative DNS*:  8.8.4.4
7. To share your Wi-Fi Internet adapter with Time Capsule you have to go to your Wi-Fi card in the *Sharing* tab and enable sharing with Ethernet connection by checking the option *Allow other network user to connect to through this computer's Internet connection*.

---

The Internet connection might be not working if you have Norton Internet security. To be able to share Wi-Fi you need to change Norton firewall rules. You can check which rule is blocking the Wi-Fi connection by looking in firewall log in the Norton History tab.